# How can I improve my question about transparent toolbar icons in Win32?

Tags: support, questions, specific-question, downvotes

I have recently [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58751417/win32-how-to-add-png-as-toolbar-icon) about using transparent PNGs as toolbar icons in a Win32 application. It has received multiple downvotes, and I cannot understand why. Without understanding the reason for these downvotes, I cannot improve my question.

According to the downvote button tooltip, one possibility is:

> This question does not show research effort

but I did: I've pasted the code I tried and explained what I've tried, what I searched on the web, etc.

Another possibility is that the question is "unclear", but I made it clear in this question that I want to know **how to add a PNG as a toolbar icon**. What more can I do to clarify my question?

A final possibility is that the question is "not useful". However, I think this is a general problem that would be a net positive contribution to the Stack Overflow knowledge base. Adding a PNG as a toolbar icon is very important because the 24-bpp bitmap ended up looking really bad!

What else have I missed? Can someone explain what the problem is with my question so that I can fix it and avoid the same problem in the future?

Comment: It is a [c++] culture problem, use [visual-c++] instead.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**I am honestly not sure why your question was downvoted so heavily.** One downvote is hardly anything to worry about, but you're right to start questioning when the score goes to −4 (as it was prior to my edit).

One thing that immediately jumps out at me is that you use some ***very* non-standard formatting**. In the original draft of your question, you had used some weird Unicode characters to simulate emphasis, instead of just using either bold or italic formatting. When you quote things, as in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58751417/how-can-i-add-a-transparent-png-as-a-toolbar-icon#comment103805506_58754216), you use some bizarre combination of brackets and asterisks, instead of quotation marks which are standard in the English language. You might not think that formatting is a big deal, but it makes your question *hard to read* and therefore *hard to understand*.

Your code was also not well formatted, in the sense that **horizontal scrolling was required** in order for someone to read it. This is not entirely your fault. It is rather the consequence of two things: Stack Overflow's relatively narrow viewport and Win32's rather verbose naming conventions. Still, the solution is entirely within your control: judicious use of line-breaks.

Finally, there is possibly the issue that **you have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)**. Your *real* problem is that you cannot figure out how to display a transparent image in a Win32 toolbar. You've decided that the solution to this is to load a PNG, which supports transparency, instead of a bitmap, so you've framed your question around this. However, that is not the best solution. A PNG is, in fact, a red herring, and trying to figure out how to load a PNG in Win32 introduces a massive additional layer of complexity that you simply do not need. If you want to display a transparent icon in a toolbar, you just need a 32-bpp bitmap. These are fully supported and require minimal effort. But, the way you've asked your question, it makes it sound like the *best* solution is not one that you would consider to be an acceptable solution. These types of questions are frustrating for experts to answer. I want to write an answer that tells you how to load a transparent bitmap, thus solving your real problem, but I am somewhat concerned that you'll not find this satisfactory because it doesn't involve the use of a PNG.

Again, I want to emphasize that those are only my observations and suggestions about things for you to take into consideration for possible future improvement. They do not, in my mind, justify the −4 score on that question. But there isn't anything you or I can do about downvotes that have been cast; what has happened has happened.

As a bonus, I have heavily revised both your Meta question (to make it less accusatory regarding downvotes) and your main question on Stack Overflow, addressing the first two issues brought up above and also improving your English grammar/syntax. Hopefully this will be educational to you as well. And at least it'll stop you from receiving any further downvotes.

Comment: It also renders the text gibberish to screen readers and anything else that isn't OCR.

Comment: Thanks so much for explaining and helping to revise, I learned quite a lot from this post. Btw, I've posted a question about the X part prior to this, that is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58749796/win32-unable-to-add-custom-toolbar-icon-having-transparency/58752180?noredirect=1#comment103808098_58752180. Since PNG is not needed and just using 32bpp is well to make the transparency, can you give any resource or reference how I can get the 32bpp to work?

Comment: @Akuta The key is passing the `LR_CREATEDIBSECTION` flag to `LoadImage`. That will allow you to load a 32-bpp bitmap, preserving the alpha channel in the process because it doesn't convert to a DDB. Create your image list with the format `ILC_COLOR32`, and then simply add that DIB section using `ImageList_Add`. The only trick here is that you need a *pre-multiplied* 32-bpp bitmap to load, so you need an image editor that is capable of writing one of those out. Gimp will do it for sure; so will Photoshop, if you're rich enough to afford it. I used to use IcoFX for this, back when it was free.

Comment: It works!!! YOU SAVED ME!!!!!!

Comment: Your post requires quite a bit of __vertical scrolling__ ;)

Comment: It was reasonable of him to guess he can have an alpha channel in his image if he just used PNG. He missed that you cannot use `LoadImage()` on a compressed PNG image (you should go thru [GDI+](https://bobobobo.wordpress.com/2010/11/06/gdi/)), but hey that's what the job of the answerers is about.

Comment: BTW getting BMP to support the alpha channel [was quite hard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369649/how-to-convert-32-bit-bmp-to-contain-alpha-channel) -- people used to (and still do) use [TGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truevision_TGA) if they wanted an uncompressed bitmap with alpha.